# control an interactive terminal program with a layer of abstraction

Tags: bash, process, io, io-redirection, fifo

I have a desire to run a paged command (usually a git diff, but could just be some other program of mine piped into `less`) in a terminal, which is fully interactive, and yet which is externally controllable. Initially just being able to terminate and restart the internal process would be fine, but being able to inject input interactively would be nice.

I think a straightforward way to do this might be to have a bash script that simply runs the internal command, which let's assume is `git diff`.

I am going to script my text editor vim in such a way that when I save a file, it will "send a signal" that the aforementioned bash script has registered for in some way. On this event, it shall interrupt the interactive child `less` process (e.g. giving it a SIGTERM seems to sort of work, though it fails to repaint) and run it again. This way I can live-update my git diff by just saving my file.

My other use case could use the same framework: I want the token that my cursor hovers on in my editor to be used for searching the project, to find all other instances of it. Here, the trigger would be different from and more frequent than saving the buffer, for example.

The reason that interactivity should be maintained (e.g. that the terminal is connected to STDIN) is so that i may use mouse/keys to scroll up and down inside the pager interactively.

One straightforward and seemingly brittle way to achieve this would be to configure vim to directly give a SIGTERM to the less or a SIGKILL to the parent `git diff` (just from empirical testing this is what appears to work on my Mac).

But I want the logic and implementation of how to kill the inner interactive process to live inside the shell script.

I was thinking I could use a fifo and send some protocol messages which the shell script interprets. But it would seem that what happens is terminal interactive standard input is passed through the shell script... I would potentially need some kind of daemon or something managed by it as well. There needs to be another component listening for the event.

Which leads me to wonder: Maybe this means that a more practical and simpler way to implement this is using a runtime such as node.js that could give me asynchronous control or other methods of i/o multiplexing or async i/o. It stays idle, and pipes/forwards stdin (interaction) through to the child. It also listens asynchronously to a fifo or other IPC method and will act on commands received from it, e.g. to inject further interactive input or kill/restart the child...

It seems like there should be canonical bashisms to implement this, though i feel like i might remember how to do this with lower level OS APIs like `select` (what I traditionally remember from my studies as being i/o multiplexing), it is possible that multiplexing like this is outside the scope of a shell, the shell has a lot of sugar and capabilities around i/o *redirection*.

Comment: Well, you have enough SO reputation to know that your question does not look like a MCVE.

Comment: You are absolutely correct

Comment: This sounds like you want to create an emacs inferior shell which you can control, send commands to, search, save, etc.  If you are familiar with emacs, this should be straight-forward, if not, you can ignore my comment.

Comment: Yes but I am a Vim person, plus, the main goal here is to have a separate terminal that Vim (or any other program) can control.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up to my rambling question.

I've continued down this path and explored a few options. I'm more or less building a node.js app that uses explicitly defined (and non-terminfo checked) terminal escape codes to implement my own pager tool that can do exactly what I want it to do and no more and no less.

I have also been building up automated testing infrastructure around this capability imlpemented via tmux (e.g. with its `capture-pane` command). For example, to test that paging works properly, i can check that after opening a buffer that after scrolling down 3 pages and back up 2 pages that the output is identical to what it displayed after 1 page.

Although it can very well be argued that it maybe should just be a simple ncurses app, I have found it a rewarding experience getting down and dirty into this stuff and continuing to use typescript, which I already write a lot for other tasks, and it helps to continue to build experience with that language. Certainly not the ideal language or runtime for this kind of purpose built tool, but that is okay.